# How to place the jumpers on Xavier NX to put it in Force Recovery mode?

Tags: jetson

I am trying to flash a new Xavier NX kit using SDK Manager and I need to put it in Force Recovery mode for the SDK Manager to recognize it. From [these](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=Jetson_Xavier_NX/Development/Building_the_Kernel_from_Source#Jetson_Xavier_NX_Recovery_Mode) instructions, it is mentioned to 'place a jumper across' pins 9 and 10 (GND and FC REC). I am not sure how to 'place' this jumper.

I have [these](https://smile.amazon.de/-/en/20cm-Female-Booster-Cables-Arduino/dp/B0876VFJS9/ref=sr_1_5?crid=1MTNIZKTCD713&dchild=1&keywords=starthilfekabel+arduino&qid=1603786577&sprefix=jumper+cables%2Caps%2C212&sr=8-5) jumper cables with me and I have two of them (from one end) put onto the pins 9 and 10 and the other end is free. How should I proceed?

I have flashed TX2s before but there were physical buttons on TX2 board and not these pins. Any specific instructions are massively appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I have also asked this question on NVIDIA Developer [forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-place-the-jumpers-on-xavier-nx-to-put-it-in-force-recovery-mode/158040) and I am awaiting an answer. I hoped here would also be a suitable place to ask.